# How can I determine the order of which I perform a join of two relations?

Tags: sql, database, schema, relation, relational-algebra

Given the following relational schema:

> Instructor(**name**, office, phone, email)
>   Course(**course_no**, title, instructor_name)
>   //Instructor_name is a foreign key that references Instructor

When I want to show the names and offices of all instructors that teach a specific course, lets say that course is Databases I for example.

[image]

Why is course joined with Instructor and not the other way around? What difference does it make and how would I go about figuring out which one comes first?

Comment: For an `inner join` it doesn't make a difference, logically.  There might be a difference in terms of performance; the database optimizer decides which is better for performance reasons.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But in this particular example, why would it be incorrect to switch course with instructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order of join clauses affect the query plan in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191497/why-does-the-order-of-join-clauses-affect-the-query-plan-in-sql-server)